# Is it possible to link two Azure active directories together?

Tags: azure, microsoft-office-365

My company recently migrated from GoDaddy email to GoDaddy's O365 offering. Unfortunately, this means our logins are now split between

- **@contoso.com** only for accessing email
- **@contoso.onmicrosoft.com** for the rest of O365 (azure, onedrive, etc.).

I'm not familiar with all the offerings of Azure, but it seems like we should be able to link those domains so users don't have to switch between accounts to access their emails or the rest of office365. Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst you can not link tenants, you can add one or more custom domains into a tenant.  When you create a new tenant, it will always have a abc.onmicrosoft.com tenant domain where abc is your own identifier, however if you own abc.com, you can add this as a custom domain.  Log into the Office admin portal, and go to Setup -> Domains and tehn click Add Domain.  You can add abc.com as a custom domain.  You will need to verify you own the domain, so Azure will give you a TXT record for you to add to the DNS for the domain, and in the background, check for this record to verify the domain.

Once verified, you can add users using any of the domains in your tenant, so you can add fred@abc.onmicrosoft.com and/or fred@abc.com.  If your abc.com email is hosted elsewhere currently, you will need to migrate the mailboxes to O365 from your current Exchange Server, and also set the correct MX records to point to O365 email.

From your desciption, your original domain is NOT a tenant, just a hosted email service from GoDaddy, so moving the domain to O365 should not be a problem, and GoDaddy should be able to help with this.

Answer (score 1):

By the sounds of it you now have 2 Azure AD Tenants, the Contoso.com one and @contoso.onmicrosoft.com. These are two entirely seperate identity stores that have no awareness of each other at all. Ideally you would not have got in this state, and used a single tenant from the start.

There is no such thing as trusts in Azure AD, or an other way to link two tenants together directly. You really only have a few options if you want a single account:

- Get Godaddy to use your existing contoso.onmicrosoft.com tenant rather than creating a new one
- Move to using non-godaddy office 365 and use your existing contoso.onmicrosoft.com AAD tenant
- Invite users from your contoso.com tenant as guests to your contoso.onmicrosoft.com tenant and grant them rights to resource they need. This will work for Azure resources, not so sure it will work for OneDrive

Comment: Thanks Sam, that's what I was afraid of. The perils of using GoDaddy!